# Using shapeless tags with LabelledGenerics

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist, labelled-generic

Suppose I'd like to traverse case class generic representation as described [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes)

I've defined some typeclass to describe fields:

```
trait Described[X] extends (X => String)
object Described{
  def apply[X](x: X)(implicit desc: Described[X]) = desc(x)
}
```

Defined some instance:

```
implicit object DoubleDescribed extends Described[Double]{
  def apply(x: Double) =  x.formatted("%01.3f")
}
```

And general user:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftFolder

object DescrFolder extends Poly2{
  implicit def field[X, S <: Symbol](implicit desc: Described[X],
                                              witness: Witness.Aux[S]):
  Case.Aux[Seq[String], FieldType[S, X], Seq[String]] =
  at[Seq[String], FieldType[S, X]](
    (descrs, value) => descrs :+ f"${witness.value.name}: ${desc(value)}")
}

def describe[T <: Product, Repr <: HList](struct: T)
      (implicit lgen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T,Repr],
                folder: LeftFolder.Aux[Repr, Seq[String], DescrFolder.type, Seq[String]]
                             ): String = {
  val repr = lgen.to(struct)
  val descrs = folder(repr,Vector())
  descrs.mkString(struct.productPrefix + "{", ",", "}")
}
```

So now i could write

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double)
describe(Point(1,2,3.0))
```

and get

> res1: String = Point{x: 1,000,y: 2,000,z: 3,000}

Now i'd like to define some field metadata using `shapeless` tags:

```
import tag._
trait Invisible
val invisible = tag[Invisible]
implicit def invisibleDescribed[X](implicit desc: Described[X])
             : Described[X @@ Invisible] =
  new Described[X @@ Invisible]{
    def apply(x: X @@ Invisible) = desc(x: X) + "[invisible]"
  }
```

so `Described(invisible(0.5))` now succesfully produces

> res2: String = 0,500[invisible]

But with redefined

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double @@ Invisible)

describe(Point(1,2,invisible(3.0)))
```

yields compilation error:

> Error: diverging implicit expansion for type
>   `LeftFolder.Aux[this.Out,Seq[String],DescrFolder.type,Seq[String]]`
>   starting with method `invisibleDescribed` in class ...

I presume that type `X with Tag[Y] with KeyTag[K,X]` is not identifying as `FieldType[S, X]` but could not guess how to fix it.

How could one define proper `LeftFolder` for such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue does not involve `shapeless` at all. It can be actually simplified as:

```scala
trait Described[T]
trait Invisible

implicit val doubleDescribed: Described[Double] = ???

implicit def invisibleDescribed[T](
  implicit desc: Described[T]
): Described[T with Invisible] = ???

implicitly[Described[Double with Invisible]]
```

`Double @@ Invisible` can be "represented" as `Double with Invisible`. Note that `Double with Invisible <: Double`.

When the compiler tries to get an implicit `Described[Double with Invisible]` it correctly complains about diverging implicit expansion: `doubleDescribed` and `invisibleDescribed`.

Going back to your original code, an easy fix could be to just rewrite `invisibleDescribed` as:

```scala
implicit def invisibleDescribed[X, I <: X @@ Invisible](
  implicit desc: Described[X]
): Described[I] = new Described[I]{
  def apply(x: I) = desc(x: X) + "[invisible]"
}
```